# Python encode list 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, encode

trying to remove \u0141 from this list which i am trying to insert into my database

```
results=[['The Squid Legion', '0', u'Banda \u0141ysego', '1', ["\nRazer's Clash of the Gods EU #12 - \nChallonge\n"]], ['Romanian eSports', '1', 'Love', '0', ["\nRazer's Clash of the Gods EU #12 - \nChallonge\n"]]]

results =[[x.encode('ascii', 'ignore')  for x in l] for l in results]
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Your list is at least 3 levels deep but you're only iterating 2 levels.

Comment: And some of your strings are only 2 levels deep.

Comment: The last `x` for each `l` is a list.

Comment: can you please explain ? I am still new to this

Comment: @user3386406: your list structure is `[[smth, smth, [smth]], ...]` but your algorithm expects `[[smth, smth, smth], ...]`; see my answer for a working algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first list in your "big list" itself contains a list `["\nRazer's Clash of the Gods EU #12 - \nChallonge\n"]`, which obviously doesn't have an `encode()` method on it.

So what happens in your algorithm is this:

```
[[somestring.encode, somestring.encode, somestring.encode, [somestring].encode, ...]
```

You could use a simple recursive algorithm though:

```
def recursive_ascii_encode(lst):
    ret = []
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, basestring):  # covers both str and unicode
            ret.append(x.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        else:
            ret.append(recursive_ascii_encode(x))
    return ret

print recursive_ascii_encode(results)
```

outputs:

```
[['The Squid Legion', '0', 'Banda ysego', '1', ["\nRazer's Clash of the Gods EU #12 - \nChallonge\n"]], ['Romanian eSports', '1', 'Love', '0', ["\nRazer's Clash of the Gods EU #12 - \nChallonge\n"]]]
```

Of course that's actually a special case of a more general recursive map, which, refactored, looks like this:

```
def recursive_map(lst, fn):
    return [recursive_map(x, fn) if isinstance(x, list) else fn(x) for x in lst]

print recursive_map(results, lambda x: x.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```